# How to control the number of particles with a custom slider

Tags: python

I define have defined an IntProperty, like so:

```
bpy.types.Scene.mycount_particles = bpy.props.IntProperty(
    name = "particle count", 
    default = 300, 
    min =0,
    max=10000,     
    description = "Short description of your prop, to show in the popup"
    )
```

And the I put it in my Panel (Hello Word Panel)

```
row.prop(context.scene, "mycount_particles", slider=True)
```

[image]

But now,  I need my slider to update number of particles, using a Python script itself and not drivers.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an update function to your property which would be called whenever you change the that property :

```
def update_particles(self, context):
    bpy.data.particles['ParticleSettings'].count =bpy.context.scene.mycount_particles 

bpy.types.Scene.mycount_particles = bpy.props.IntProperty(
    name = "particle count", 
    default = 300, 
    min =0,
    max=10000, 
    update = update_particles,   
    description = "particles number of the first particle system"
    )
```

Comment: @IssanouKamardineIK you're welcome, and If the answer solved your problem, could you please mark it as accepted